# java referencing objects that are not in scope

Tags: java, oop, object, scope

one question that always pops up when my java project gets bigger is if there is an easy way of making references to a specific object thats cannot be referenced by super or getParent(). The following graph should illustrates my current problem:
[image]

For every FileListItem I want to instatiate a new FileListItemController which needs methods from ProtocolController. Is there a way of referencing the ProtocolController object instatiated by main in the FileListItems other than passing it on through mainWindow, FileListContentPanel, FileListItems?

---

First thanks to all your answers.

I am using the model, view, control pattern for my project.

The singleton pattern sounds interesting but my feeling is that it does not solve my issue. Here is some code to illustrate my problem:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        ProtocolController pc = new ProtocolController();
        mainWindow mw = new mainWindow();

    }
}
public class ProtocolController {
    File protocol;
    public ProtocolController(File protocol){
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

    public void writeSomethingToProtocolFile(String something){
        // write something to th protcol file specified by the object
    }
}
public class mainWindow {
    public mainWindow(){
        FileListContentPanel flcp = new FileListContentPanel();
    }
}
public class FileListContentPanel {
    public FileListContentPanel(){
        int numListItems = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            FileListItem fli = new FileListItem();
            FileListItemController flic = new FileListItemController(fli);
        }
    }
}
public class FileListItemController {

    public FileListItemController(FileListItem fli){

    }
    public void addSomethingToProtocol(String something){
        // at this point I want to use a method from the ProtocolController class instantiated by the main method
    }
}
```

Comment: @Martin Can you please show us the pseduo code for the `main` method and any other methods so that it is easier for us to understand the flow of your application and the number of instances created for each class shown above?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches for this.

For instance, if you only need one `ProtocolController` instance, you could use the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Each `FileListItemController` is then able to retrieve the same `ProtocolController` object.

```
class ProtocolController {

    private static instance;

    private ProtocolController() { }

    public static ProtocolController getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ProtocolController();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

You can then get `ProtocolController.getInstance()` from within `FileListItemController` and then call the desired method.

Comment: The OP said. *For every FileListItem I want to instatiate a new FileListItemController*.

Comment: @CKing Correct. The example above governs this requirement.

Comment: Now that you have addressed my previous comment in your edit, this part is still to be address : *For every FileListItem I want to instatiate a new FileListItemController which needs methods from ProtocolController*.  The point I am trying to make is, there is a lot to be understood from the OP before we can answer the question and it would be wise to wait for all the information.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have only one instance of `FileListItemController`**, you can use [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) with "Lazy instantiation".

And `ProtocolController` instantiates `FileListItemController` like this :

```
FileListItemController fileListItemControllerInstance = FileListItemController.getInstance();
```

### EDIT

**If each `FileListItem` references one `FileListItemController`**, you can use a `Factory` ([Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern))

In this case, your `ProtocolController` can instiate a `FileListItemController` factory. You can pass `ProtocolController` reference to the factory if needed.

Then `FileListItem` can use this factory to create new `FileListItemController` instances.

Comment: The OP said. *For every FileListItem I want to instatiate a new FileListItemController*.

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood the schema that seems to represent multiple instances of `FileListItem` referencing one instance of `FileListItemController` (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a use case for Model-View-Controller design pattern.

Your `FileListItem` objects are model (You'll need a new class to hold them). Both Controller and View (`FileListControlPanel`) get a reference to Model. Controller then uses methods on model to change its contents, and View subscribes to model's events to show the changes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 0):

`Window` doesn't need to know about the protocol. In fact, `Panel` doesn't need to know about the protocol either.

Use dependency injection.

---

## Panel

Since `Panel` creates the controllers, `Panel` will need a reference to `Protocol`. So you'll need to inject the protocol into the panel.

```
class Panel {
    public Panel(Protocol protocol) {
        for(...) {
            Item item = new Item();
            Controller controller = new Controller(item, protocol);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't recommend populating the list in the constructor like this, but I kept it so the code is familiar.

## Window

To prevent `Window` knowing about `Protocol`, you should inject the panel.

```
class Window {
    public Window(Panel panel) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

## Update `main`

With these new changes, you'd be interfacing with your types as follows:

```
Protocol protocol = new Protocol();
Panel panel = new Panel(protocol);
Window window = new Window(panel);
```

Now `Window` doesn't need to depend on `Protocol`.

---

## Introduce a factory

I mentioned how `Panel` doesn't need to depend on `Protocol` either.

It's the `Controller` that uses the protocol; the panel only references the protocol so it can pass it to newly created controllers. The protocol is needed for the creation of controllers.

You could introduce a factory to handle the creation of controllers. The factory would reference the protocol:

```
class ControllerFactory {
    private Protocol protocol;

    public ControllerFactory(Protocol protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

    public Controller newController(Item item) {
        return new Controller(item, protocol);
    }
}
```

`Panel` would now depend on the factory instead of the protocol:

```
class Panel {
    public Panel(ControllerFactory factory) {
        factory = factory;

        for(...) {
            Item item = new Item();
            Controller controller = factory.newController(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Your new usage would be as follows:

```
Protocol protocol = new Protocol();
ControllerFactory factory = new ControllerFactory(protocol);
Panel panel = new Panel(factory);
Window window = new Window(panel);
```

Neither `Window` or `Panel` know about the protocol.